# Function declarations and how they create variables in the current scope

Tags: javascript

I was reading this article about js functions.
https://dmitripavlutin.com/6-ways-to-declare-javascript-functions/

and it says "The function declaration creates a variable in the current scope with the identifier equal to function name. This variable holds the function object."

So I did some experiments to learn more.

```
function a () {
    return 1;
}
console.log(typeof a === "function")
console.log(typeof a === "number")
```

This outputs
True
False

Which isn't surprising, then when I run this.

```
var a = 1;
function a () {
    return 1;
}
console.log(typeof a === "function")
console.log(typeof a === "number")
```

The output is
False
True

So although a is allocated to a number and then later allocated to a function, it ends up being a number in the end.

Is there some kind of rule that says variable declarations override function declarations or is there more to it?

Comment: Maybe this is due to hoisting. I am not sure but that can be a reason. I am on phone so can't check. Please try replacing `var` with `const`. Let us know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function declarations are *hoisted* to the top of their containing function (or the outermost block). Your lower code is equivalent to the following:

```js
var a = function a () {
    return 1;
}
// next line reassigns `a` to number:
a = 1;
console.log(typeof a === "function")
console.log(typeof a === "number")
```

If you log `a` before the line `a = 1`, you'll see that it is indeed a function before it gets reassigned:

```js
console.log(typeof a);
var a = 1;
console.log(typeof a);
function a () {
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: aren't variable hoisted as well? I guess function are just hoisted higher?

Comment: Variable *creation* is hoisted (eg `var a;`, doesn't make a difference here though), but variable *assignment* is not hoisted (eg `a = 10;`, assignment will always occur on the same line as you expect it to occur).

Comment: ahh that makes sense. Thanks.